# Background Tasks in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bing-maps, portable-class-library, winrt-async

Ths situtation:

I get from different internet locations, json objects.

These containsmany Geocoordinates that I put onto a BingMap. 
That works perfect very well.

The Problem:

but when I fetch the data from the internet locations I get a blocking ui. 
Is there a method to run that in background?

I tried the async functionality but I get there a blocking UI too..

Here some code
Caller

```
public async void Caller_Click(){
    await jsonDataClass.DoOperations();
}
```

The method in the jsonDataClass

```
public async Task<bool> DoOperations(){
    // do requests and some stuff..
    var fetchedElements = getdata(); // not async, because its in a portable lib
    foreach (var element in fetchedElements)
      OnEvent(element); // raises an event to assing the element to the Bing map
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't ignore compiler warnings. In particular, if you have an `async` method that doesn't use `await`, then the compiler will specifically tell you that the method is *not* asynchronous and will run synchronously.

The first thing I would recommend is to change `getdata` so that it is `async`. The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package extends `async` support to portable class libraries.

If that's not possible, then you'll have to execute `getdata` on a background thread, like this:

```
public async Task<bool> DoOperations()
{
  var fetchedElements = await Task.Run(() => getdata());
  foreach (var element in fetchedElements)
    OnEvent(element);
}
```

P.S. The term "background task" has a [special meaning in WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.aspx). What you actually need is to run code on a thread pool thread (or background thread), which is different than what WinRT calls a "background task".